# Heroku application cloned within a Github folder

Tags: git, heroku, github

I have the scenario where I have a GitHub repo, which I have cloned to my computer - and which obviously has a .git/ directory pointing to the GitHub origin - and then I've cloned a Heroku app - which has its own default .git/ directory pointing to the Heroku origin - into that folder structure...

So you can see my problem - now I effectively have nested git projects, where my directory structure looks like this:

```
/my-github-app
  .git
  .gitignore
  README
  LICENSE
  my-heroku-app
   .git
   /app etc
```

What is the best way to deal with this?

I will be doing the bulk of my work inside the Heroku app anyways, so my nest workflow assumption would be

- blah blah changes --> heroku commit
- deploys --> heroku push
- cd ../
- version tag --> github commit/push

... not ***TOO*** onerous...

But I'm sure there has to be a better/smarter way ... no ??

**EDIT**

Of course, as *solocommand* says, there is GitHub integration for Heroku... so, it would look like this: ?

1. setup app on heroku
2. setup app on github
3. clone heroku app
4. clone github app
5. add heroku dir to github dir
6. integrate repository to app
7. work + commit in github
8. push to github, heroku builds and deploys

But i'd still have the nested .git folder issue, and have to make sure my git shell / client would be in the right directory... which If i use a gui front end, is easy enough to keep static...

Comment: Are you actually going to do anything with your `my-github-app` repository? Personally I would just forgo the wrapping repository and just use the `my-heroku-app` repo. That said, what you would want to do in your situation is to bring in your `my-heroku-app` as a submodule inside your `my-github-app` repo. Then do a submodule update and version tag in the containing repo.

Comment: Yeah, it certainly reminds me of a submodule pattern...

Comment: The GitHub repo is mostly for show, but I may be working on this across computers, so it's an easy way to sync...

Comment: You could also look into the [Github integration](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration) for Heroku. Would allow you to keep your code in GH and set up what would trigger deployments within Heroku.

Comment: @solocommand i have seen that - and actually worked with it on a project before - but what would the flow be for the initial setup? (may edit OP)

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but it looks like you just need to link a GH repository with a heroku app and configure how it deploys.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103784/discussion-between-solocommand-and-jesses-co-tt).